# Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

Tags: json

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    @MessageMapping("/websocket")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public List<ChatMessage> send(@Payload List<ChatMessage> message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hi");
            Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return message;
    }
}


const sendMessage = (content) => {
    if (stompClient) {
      const message = [{ content: content, sender: 'user' }];
      stompClient.send(
        '/app/websocket',
        JSON.stringify(message)
      );
      console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    } else {
      console.error('Stomp client is not initialized.');
    }
  };
```

controller/Chat.js

데이터가 서버로 잘못 전달됨 json형식으로 데이터를 받지 못하는것 같음
frame
:
body
:
{}
command
:
"SEND"
headers
:
0
:
"["
1
:
"{"
2
:
"""
3
:
"c"
4
:
"o"
5
:
"n"
6
:
"t"
7
:
"e"
8
:
"n"
9
:
"t"
10
:
"""
11
:
":"
12
:
"""
13
:
"g"
14
:
"o"
15
:
"""
16
:
","
17
:
"""
18
:
"s"
19
:
"e"
20
:
"n"
21
:
"d"
22
:
"e"
23
:
"r"
24
:
"""
25
:
":"
26
:
"""
27
:
"u"
28
:
"s"
29
:
"e"
30
:
"r"
31
:
"""
32
:
"}"
33
:
"]"
destination
:
"/app/websocket"
[[Prototype]]
:
Object
이 형식으로 보내짐

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at \[Source: (byte\[\])"\[object Object\]"; line: 1, column: 9\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:255) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.AbstractMessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractMessageConverter.java:183) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.converter.CompositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(CompositeMessageConverter.java:70) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:144) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:118) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:115) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:567) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:511) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.annotation.support.SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.handleMatch(SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler.java:93) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:522) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.AbstractMethodMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMethodMessageHandler.java:457) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:144) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) \~\[na:na\]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) \~\[na:na\]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) \~\[na:na\]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'object': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at \[Source: (byte\[\])"\[object Object\]"; line: 1, column: 9\]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.\_constructError(JsonParser.java:2477) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase.\_reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:760) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.\_reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3699) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.\_handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2787) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.\_nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:908) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:794) \~\[jackson-core-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.\_deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:350) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.\_readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3866) \~\[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3\]
at org.springframework.messaging.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter.convertFromInternal(MappingJackson2MessageConverter.java:241) \~\[spring-messaging-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2\]
... 15 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you receive at server side and it's not a valid JSON. You should probably fix this line `JSON.stringify(message)` at your client side

Comment: 콘솔에는 제대로 json형식으로 나오는데 저부분을 수정해야하나요?